# Why is this function much slower when named?

Tags: haskell

I have a function that computes the number of divisors of an integer:

```
numDivisor = ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] )
```

When I run this function in GHCI with or without giving it a name, there is a **constant** ~1.4 times performance hit. Example copyable to ghci:

```
:set +s
x = 20000000
( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] ) x
numDivisor = ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] )
numDivisor x
```

and the results:

```
Prelude> ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] ) x
72
(8.67 secs, 3,040,063,784 bytes)
Prelude> numDivisor x
72
(12.68 secs, 4,000,064,048 bytes)
```

It doesn't matter if x is 20000000, 200000 or is below 10000, the hit is ~1.4, also it happens when I name my function in a "where" something. In the next example I calculate the divisors for all the numbers from 1 to x, then drop them:

```
:set +s
x = 10000
divisorListAnon = map ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] ) [1..] 
filter odd $ filter even $ take x divisorListAnon
:{
divisorListNamed  = map numDivisor [1..]
    where numDivisor = ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] )
:}
filter odd $ filter even $ take x divisorListNamed
```

the results:

```
Prelude> filter odd $ filter even $ take x divisorListAnon
[]
(21.17 secs, 7,613,246,464 bytes)
Prelude> filter odd $ filter even $ take x divisorListNamed
[]
(29.84 secs, 9,213,726,504 bytes)
```

Anyone can give some pointers what's going on? Also how can I use and name this subroutine without this performance hit? I'd prefer to give it a name, and don't use it anonymous.

Thank you,

---

edit:

ubuntu 20.04, ghc 8.6.5 from the ubuntu distributed ghc package, not stack

Comment: There isn't really any point investigating a 1.4× performance difference between functions defined in GHCi. No function you define in GHCi will ever have good performance (unless it calls pre-compiled helpers to do all heavy lifting). If performance matters, you need to put your functions in a file and compile it with optimisations.

Comment: Cool. Compiling (with *or without* optimizations) does indeed wipe out the differences here. Still, the question is a fascinating one... why *does* naming it make such a big difference? My first thought was that it's an `Int`/`Integer` thing, but both should be defaulting in the same way. Second thought was that this was a fusion thing, but there are only two lists, so if one did fusion and the other didn't, I'd expect a nice clean 100% difference in allocations, not the 20%-30% that's shown here. So odd!

Comment: If you do `numDivisor = ( \(n::Int) -> length $ filter (\x -> n \`mod\` x == 0) [1..n] )`, in other words a monomorphic input instead of Integral a, it runs even faster than the lambda version.

Comment: Doing `( \(n::Int) -> length $ filter (\x -> n \`mod\` x == 0) [1..n] ) x` renders identical results. I think it's related to specialization.

Comment: `numDivisor = ( \(n::Int) -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] )` results me in an error : `error:
    Illegal type signature: ‘Int’
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables`
But you're saying that it's an Int/Integer difference. So annoying! Also, thank you!

Comment: That the difference goes away in compiled code even without optimisations is probably not an `Int` vs `Integer` thing, but rather the monomorphism restriction. It's off by default in GHCi but on by default in compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

`` ( \n -> length $ filter (\x -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n] ) x `` has the type `Num a => Int`. The "hidden" type variable `a` (the type of `x`) is defaulted to `Integer`. This happens, I suppose, before GHCi generates its bytecode, and it's smart enough to use operations from the `Integer` specialization instead of the generic `Num` methods when the numeric type is known to be `Integer`.

`let`-binding the function generalizes it to `forall a. Num a => a -> Int`. In the Core intermediate language, the function takes a `Num a` dictionary as an argument, and all operations on the numeric values go through the dictionary. GHCi compiles the function to bytecode without knowing what the type `a` will be.

You can work around this in GHCi by giving `numDivisor` the explicit type `Integer -> Int`. GHC (the compiler) will most likely automatically specialize it at `Integer`, so there will be no performance difference.

You could also work around this by *en*abling the monomorphism restriction in GHCi, which will cause `x` and `numDivisor` to immediately be defaulted to `Integer` and `Integer -> Int`.